# How to call oracle stored functions in php?

Tags: php, oracle

My PHP code is here:

```
<?php        
    $conn = oci_connect('user', 'test', 'localhost/db');              
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();           
        }
    else
    {
     $st_en=oci_parse($conn, " begin :r:=admin.encrypt_password('$row_pd[0]');end; ");
     ociexecute($st_en);
      while (($row_en=oci_fetch_row($st_en))!=false)//checking 
        {
             if ( $pword==$row_en[0])//password matching
            {
                      echo "success";
            }
            else
            {
              echo "sorryyyyyyyyyy";
            }                   
        }
        oci_free_statement($stid); 

        oci_close($conn);//connection close
    }        
    ?>
```

when I execute this code I getting this error:

`error code ora01008 occurred, not all variables bound`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`oci_bind_by_name()`](http://php.net/oci_bind_by_name) to bind your variable `r` with some actual php variable.

Comment: A good tutorial that should explain how you can bind variable for return value [PHP call Oracle function](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/12/22/php-leveraging-plsql/).. You should define variable say $returnValue and then call ` oci_bind_by_name($st_en,":r",$returnValue);` after oci_parse and before ociexecute